# Whether one hash includes another hash

Tags: ruby

Say we have "deep hashes" like:

```
b = {1 => {2 => {} }, 4 => {} }
a = {1 => {2 => {3 => {} }}, 4 => {}, 5 => "123" }
```

or

```
b = {1 => {children: {2 => {children: false} }}}
a = {1 => {name: "name", surname:"sur", children: {2 => {name: "name", surname:"sur", children: false}}}, 3 => {}}
```

`a` includes `b` but not versa vice;

Here's my try:

```
class Hash

  def >=(b)
    eq ||= true     
    b.each do |k, v| 
      if !(self.include? k) 
        eq = false 
      elsif ( ((self[k]&&v).is_a? Hash) && !((v||self[k]).empty?) )
        self[k]>=v 
      end 
    end

    return eq
  end
end

a >= b # true
b >= a # false
```

Short version:

```
class Hash

  def >=(b)  
    eq = true
    b.each { |k, v| eq &= !(self.include? k) ? false : ( ( ((self[k]&&v).is_a? Hash) && !((v||self[k]).empty?) ) ? self[k]>=v : true)}

    return eq
  end
end
```

My question: is there more graceful way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional approach:

```
class Hash
  def >=(other)
    other.all? do |key, value|
      if self.has_key?(key) 
        value.is_a?(Hash) ? (self[key].is_a?(Hash) && self[key] >= value) : (self[key] == value)
      else
        false
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like you're out of the competition (:

Comment: @ted: so it seems, it was an interesting question though. Note that you can also do it with the condition before the `all?`, checking if you have all the keys before doing anything: `if (other.keys - self.keys).empty? ...all? stuff here without the if.has_key nor the else... else false`