# How to compare two Hashes so to return true if both Hashes have same keys/values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, compare

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and Ruby 1.9.3. I would like to compare two `Hash`es (`A` and `B`) so to return `true` if a `Hash` (`A`) include all keys/values of the other `Hash` (`B`).

For example, given I have

```
params.inspect
# => { "action"=>"...", "controller"=>"...", "key_param1"=>"value_param1", , "key_param2"=>"value_param2", "key_param3"=>"value_param3", ... }

my_hash1.inspect
# => { "key_param1"=>"value_param1", "key_param2"=>"value_param2" }

my_hash2.inspect
# => { "key_param4"=>"value_param4", "key_param1"=>"value_param1" }

my_hash3.inspect
# => {}
```

Then I am looking for a method (or something like that) in order to make

```
params.has_same_keys_and_values_as?(my_hash1)
# => true

params.has_same_keys_and_values_as?(my_hash2)
# => false

params.has_same_keys_and_values_as?(my_hash3)
# => true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Hash
  def >=(b)  
    eq = true
    b.each { |k, v| eq &= !(self.include? k) ? false : ( ( ((self[k]&&v).is_a? Hash) && !((v||self[k]).empty?) ) ? self[k]>=v : true)}

    return eq
  end

end
params = { "action"=>"...", "controller"=>"...", "key_param1"=>"value_param1", "key_param2"=>"value_param2", "key_param3"=>"value_param3" }
my_hash1 = { "key_param1"=>"value_param1", "key_param2"=>"value_param2" }
my_hash2 = { "key_param4"=>"value_param4", "key_param1"=>"value_param1" }
my_hash3 = {}

p params >= my_hash1 #true
p params >= my_hash2 #false
p params >= my_hash3 #true
```

It'll work with "deep" hashes as well:

```
b = {1 => {2 => {} }, 4 => {} }
a = {1 => {2 => {3 => {} }}, 4 => {}, 5 => "123" }

p a >= b #true
p b >= a #false
```

P.S.

[Whether one hash includes another hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332910/whether-one-hash-includes-another-hash)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Hash#keys and Hash#values return values in the same order:

```
params.values_at(*my_hash.keys) == my_hash.values
```

Comment: Assuming that Hash#keys and Hash#values *do not* return values in the same order, what could be made to accomplish that?

Comment: `params.values_at(*my_hash.keys.sort) == my_hash.values_at(*my_hash.keys.sort)`

Comment: Sorting two the sets and comparing their elements one by one would be beneficial if we DON'T use hashes. The advantage with hashes is that we can quickly look if a value exists, so we can skip sorting and just iterate over each element in one of the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use:

```
a.slice(*b.keys) == b
```

where a and b are your hashes. note that slice is a rails method and not ruby.
in plain ruby you can write:

```
a.keep_if{|k, v| b[k]} == b
```

Comment: slice method is also included in rubyfacets: http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-class-Hash/api-method-Hash-h-slice

Comment: @davidrac - I updated the question including a case related to a `my_hash3`.

Comment: this should still work. a.slice(*b.keys) will return {}. {} == {} should return true.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This is assuming that the values/keys are not in the same order in both hashes.

You could iterate over each key in hash1 and use has_key? on hash2. Keep in mind this is naive solution that could be slow for large datasets.

Checkout has_key? and has_value? here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F

You could loop as follows:

```
hash1.each_key { |key|
    if hash2.has_key?(key)
        do whatever
    endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better way, there's an active support method for this, hash.diff, wrap it with .empty? to check if they are the same

```
{:one => 1}.diff({:one => 1}).empty?

=> true

{:one => 1}.diff({:one => 2}).empty?

=> false
```

http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Diff.html